# Backup files on Windows 10 computer

Tags: windows, backup, robocopy

I'm supposed to backup a Windows 10 computer. This means copying specific filetypes e.g. .pdf, .doc, .xls, .jpg etc.

I've tried with xcopy but the backup doesn't get complete due to the fact that the computer apparently has folderpaths that are longer than 254 characters.
Therefore I googled, and found Microsofts robocopy, which can handle that particular problem (among others).

Robocopy is a foldercopy utility and not so much a filecopy utility, but with some parameters it should be able to solve the problem.
I created a batch file witch contains these two lines (+ all the rest of the relevant filetypes)

robocopy c:\ d:\B20180602\ *.pdf /s /A-:SH

robocopy c:\ d:\B20180602\ *.doc /s /A-:SH

The odd thing is that it now copies without problems (regarding to foldernames larger than 254 characters), but the final result of this backup is incomplete. There are several subfolders that aren't copied.

Is there anybody that can give me a hint? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE #1 ***
After @selbie's advice I ran this one particular command (as Administrator):

robocopy c:\ d:\B20180602\ *.pdf /s /A-:SH

With the following result:

---

```
           Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras

Dirs :    761465    761351         1         0       113         0
```

Files :      1233      1233         0         0         0         0

Bytes :   1.464 g   1.464 g         0         0         0         0

Times :   1:58:47   0:00:50                       0:00:00   1:57:56

Speed :            30918074 Bytes/sec.

Speed :            1769.146 MegaBytes/min.

Ended : 4. juni 2018 21:32:21

Elevating to Administrator changed a lot. I will make some statistical samples tomorrow and thereby answer whether the problems is solved.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You did run your script from an elevated (Adminstrator) cmd window, right?

Comment: @selbie I didn't, so I did. Running it as Administrator changed a lot. Especially it is around 25 times more time consuming. I have inserted the result above. The strange thing is that status of dirs: 1 skipped and 113 failed.Any idea why?

Comment: @selbie Your solution worked perfectly. How can I answer this question in your favor?

Comment: Glad it worked for you.